# Started GNOME display manager.. Ubuntu 18.04 LTS GUI not booting

Tags: boot, dual-boot, gnome, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-tweak-tool

My Ubuntu PC is not booting up. I am running Windows-Ubuntu dual-boot. On booting, the initial boot animation with the Ubuntu logo shows up..
Then, it runs various checks and at last shows the following line :

```
nkre=   ] Started GNOME Display Manager. Dispatcher Service....d before the ppp link was shut down....
```

Before running into this problem, I had made a mistake (or so I think). While I was using aircrack, just after giving Ctrl+C, I gave sudo reboot in the terminal. The next time it boot up, it gets stuck here ...
Somebody please help...

Others on Stack Exchange told that this is caused because the GUI is not intializing. They told me that to solve it, you have to access tty and then reinstall gnome-shell. But then, I am unable to log into tty. It is not accepting my username and password. Please help...

Also, since my trackpad was not working in Ubuntu earlier, I had used Gnome - Tweaks to enable it.. I had also edited the desktop dock bar with dconf-editor.. I don't know if any of these started the problem..

Answer (score 0):

I had problems making a custom disk partition on the new machine I just built.

Loading Ubuntu 18.04 on it with my partition map had it ignore most all of the partitions and use one smaller one and it would not boot properly following the install.

Allowing the installer to make the map, being one large partition, a small 2Gig swap, solved the problem.  I can live with that but it gets weird on a 6TB disk...

Congrats to those doing this release, it all went really quickly to install and works great.  Just that one caveat.